# How to list only the file names of the same type in the directory?

Tags: shell

I have two groups of files in the same directory `*fmb` and `*fmx`.

I want to learn how to print *only* the file name of `fmb` files, `file1.fmb, file2.fmb, file3.fmb` will be printed as `file1, file2, file3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in *.fmb; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}"; done
```

- Using [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) `*.fmb` to match all files end with `.fmb`
- `${f%.*}` is shell syntax for [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), remove the smallest suffix matched pattern in `$f`. Here we remove the extension part `.fmb`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not thanked you earlier...I'm grateful for your answer, it helped me.